# Event Listener for tick items on charts_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

For the `charts_flutter` library, I want to be notified when a click/tap/hover event happens on a tick of an axis. I can only see how to trigger events from within axes bounds, not on the actual axis/tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your widget with a GestureDetector and implements its functions like below.

```
 GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                onDoubleTap: (){},
                child: CustomChart(),
),
```

Comment: This answer does not address the core difficulty of the question, since it says nothing about determining *which* tick-mark was tapped. The gesture-detection would need to happen from within the `charts_flutter` library, or the library needs to expose methods of attaching listeners to the tickmarks